# Is there a fourth ending for the movie "Clue" (1985)?

Tags: ending, alternate-version, clue

Rewatching the movie *Clue* from 1985, I am puzzled, as I seem to remember watching it as a kid and the ending was something about the maid being the cook(?) in disguise. I especially remember her having a set of fake, long legs in a suitcase. Does anyone know if this ending exists, is from another movie, or something third?

Comment: There was a 4th ending filmed, but it was scratched and never shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am puzzled, as I seem to remember watching it as a kid and the ending was something about the maid being the cook(?) in disguise. I especially remember her having a set of fake, long legs in a suitcase.

As I suspected this is from an entirely different movie [***Murder by Death***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_by_Death) (1976) where.... "The cook is also discovered to have been an animated mannequin, now packed in a storage crate."

[image]

Answer (score -2):

While 'Murder by Death' is also an excellent 'whodunnit' murder mystery, it has only one ending.

'Clue' has three endings. Here's an article on it:
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088930/alternateversions

I own both movies on DVD and can confirm it features three different endings.